# Sorting a list but I keep getting a error

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm still a python beginner. I need to write 2 lists to two different text files then sort each text file then finally add those two text file outputs to a new text file that is also sorted.
I need to sort the ascending order.I tried casting the numbers to str when I did this the program worked to print the unsorted list but the problem came when I added sort .Hope this makes sense.

```
number1 = [5000, 300, 4, 1, 2]
number2 = [19, 66, 8, 17, 100]

with open("numbers1.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.write(str(number1))

with open("numbers2.txt", "w") as file2:
    file2.write(str(number2))

with open("numbers1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    content = file1.read()
    content.sort()
    print(content)

with open("numbers2.txt", "r+") as file2:
    content2 = file2.read()
    content2.sort()
    print(content2)
    

#combined =  file1 + file2
#combined.sort()
#print(combined)
```

the program then gives me this error

```
content.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I have yet to write the final two sorted lists to a new text file that is also sorted

Comment: The type of the object returned by `read()` is a string. Just like you converted the list to a string when writing it to a file, you want to convert it back when reading it from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.read()` returns a string, not a list. You need to convert it back to a list if you want a list, but the format in which you're saving the list to the file in the first place isn't the best, since it creates extra characters.

It's probably a better idea to write one element of the list to each line of the file instead. Then, read the file

```
with open("numbers1.txt", "w") as file1:
    file1.writelines(str(n) for n in number1)

with open("numbers1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    content = []
    for line in file1:
        content.append(int(line))

    content.sort()
```

You could replace the read loop with a comprehension:

```
with open("numbers1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    content = [int(line) for line in file1]
    content.sort()
```

If it is an option, you could write to a *json* file instead of a regular text file. The `json` package takes care of converting the read list to the correct format when you use `json.load()`.

```
import json

with open("numbers1.json", "w") as file1:
    json.dump(numbers1, file1)

with open("numbers1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    content = json.load(file1)
    content.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the built-in module `pathlib`.

- simplifies reading/writing text or bytes to files
- takes the same args that `open()` uses
- you can still iterate on file, `with open() as file`, etc
- better cross-platform paths, and pass one object around, using `.absolute()`
- [pathlib:  basic-use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use)
- [pathlib: methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#general-properties)
- [Here's a table of `os.path` to `pathlib.Path` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module)

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

AppRoot: Path = Path('.')
path_text: Path  = AppRoot / 'numbers.txt'
path_json: Path  = AppRoot / 'numbers.json'
```

@Pranav Hosangadi's example:

```
with open("numbers1.json", "w") as file1:
    json.dump(numbers1, file1)

with open("numbers1.txt", "r+") as file1:
    content = json.load(file1)
    content.sort()
```

Can be written as

```py
content = json.loads(path_text.read_text())
content.sort()
path_json.write_text(json.dumps(content))
```

Because I saved `AppRoot`, I can from any directory refer to, for example

```
 `.../YourApp/Config/settings.json`
```

No matter what subdirectory the caller is. moving the file, or moving your app to another parent don't break.